# CICFlowmeter(pcap->csv) : TypeError: add_packet() missing 1 required positional argument: 'direction'

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, pcap, read.csv, pcap-ng

I am trying to convert pcapng to csv on a ubuntu 22 machine using CICFlowmeter  :

```
sudo cicflowmeter --file ../CSa.pcapng --csv CSaCSV.csv
```

But getting the following issue :

```
reading from file ../CSa.pcapng, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 925, in _run
    session.on_packet_received(p)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cicflowmeter-0.1.6-py3.8.egg/cicflowmeter/flow_session.py", line 86, in on_packet_received
TypeError: add_packet() missing 1 required positional argument: 'direction'
```

I have tried several things like changing versions of scapy,etc. But, so far none has worked. Appreciate your help.

Current versions :

```
scapy                    2.5.0   
numpy                    1.18.0 
scipy                    1.4.1
```